# I there any way to limit access to Redshift external schemas by table level?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am working currently in a project where we are using Redshift and Spectrum to manage some external schemas with the data stored at S3.

In order to have access to an external schema the user must belong to a group with the USAGE permission over this external schema but it seems that, with the USAGE grant this user will be able see and query ALL the external schema tables.

What I would like to do is to only grant SELECT permission for a particular table, not the whole schema.

Is that possible? I have checked the AWS docs and try different things but as the external tables have a particular nature I have not found any useful information yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly on the External tables.

[Removed the earlier approach of using views as that would not solve it]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Swapnil, I already tried with the views but I get the error: ```[0A000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: External tables are not supported in views; java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: External tables are not supported in views;```

Comment: Edited my first comment. You were too fast replying hehe.

Comment: :) I'm afraid you are not adding this "with no schema binding;" at the end of your view. If you add, it will work. If yes, let me know and i'll add that in my answer as well.

Comment: Yeah! that was it, I am now about to check if the grants works on the views. Thanks @Swapnil Pandey

Comment: It seems there is no way to achieve this as we still need to have the USAGE grant to query the new view otherwise you'll get the error: ´´´ [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: permission denied for schema <external_schema> ´´´ when query the view.

Comment: @JoseRamonFernandez yes, you do need to provide the usage grant to the Redshift schema, but the thing is by giving the usage, you won't be able to query every view in that schema. You still need to provide individual SELECT grant for each view, which was not the case if u give usage on external schema. So, you can control access for each external table/view individually with this approach.

Comment: if you agree, please consider accepting/up-voting. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific on the previous comment. I am getting the error because, although we are setting the SELECT grant on the view and granting the Redshift schema with the USAGE, we still need to have the USAGE grant on the external schema. Using an internal schema I know that just by giving the USAGE grant the user can not read the tables or views but with external schemas, once the USAGE is granted the user can query every object. To sum up, to query a view from an external table we still need to have the USAGE granted to the external schema.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. This would not solve it. Will think about it and also follow your question for any answers :)

Comment: Just a thought...If you want to manage a set of external tables and not each one individually, may be you can create multiple external schemas for specific types of objects?

Comment: Thanks @Swapnil, I really appreciate your help. The problem here is we may end having a different external schema for each user which can become quickly a nice mess. Let give it a try to see if anyone have a working workaround or I need to follow this approach. Thanks!